# herokuでTweetStream::ReconnectErrorが発生する

Tags: ruby, twitter, heroku

tweetstream を利用して特定ユーザーのtweetを監視するアプリをheroku上にデプロイしましたが、TweetStream::ReconnectError というエラーが発生しうまく動作していないようです。

ローカルで foreman を利用し動作を確認したところ問題ありませんでした。heroku上で動作させるためには何か必要なのでしょうか？

ソースコードとログをGithub上に公開しているので下記を参照ください。

ソースコード:
https://github.com/shts/nogi_tweet_observer

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'tweetstream'
require 'parse-ruby-client'
require 'uri'

Parse.init :application_id => ENV['PARSE_APP_ID'],
           :api_key        => ENV['PARSE_API_KEY']

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
  config.consumer_secret    = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
  config.oauth_token        = ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN']
  config.oauth_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET']
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

def push_notification(url) # must String
  data = { :alert => "Push from ruby sample!" + url.to_s, :url => url.to_s }
  push = Parse::Push.new(data)
  push.where = { :deviceType => "android" }
  p push.save
end

def replace_uri(s)
    str = s.dup
    uri_reg = URI.regexp(%w[http https])
    str.gsub!(uri_reg) {"#{$&}"}
    "#{$&}"
end

NOGIZAKA_BLOG = "http://blog.nogizaka46.com"

def expand_url(url)
  uri = url.kind_of?(URI) ? url : URI.parse(url)
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) { |io|
    r = io.head(uri.path)
    r['Location'] || uri.to_s
  }
end

EM.run do
  client = TweetStream::Client.new
  # 1084091587 -> 練習用
  # 317684165 -> 本番
  client.follow(1084091587) do |status|
    puts "#{status.user.screen_name}: #{status.text}"

    url = replace_uri(status.text)
    if (!url.to_s.include?("http://t.co/") && !url.to_s.include?("http://bit.ly/"))
      puts "url may be not nogizaka blog domain : " + url.to_s
    else
      url = expand_url(url)
      if (url.include?(NOGIZAKA_BLOG))
        push_notification(url)
      else
        url = expand_url(url)
        if (url.include?(NOGIZAKA_BLOG))
          push_notification(url)
        else
          puts "url may be not nogizaka blog domain"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  client.on_error do |message|
    puts "error: #{message}\n"
  end

  client.on_reconnect do |timeout, retries|
    puts "reconnecting in: #{timeout} seconds\n"
  end

end
```

エラーログの要点部分:
https://github.com/shts/nogi_tweet_observer/issues/1

```
2015-02-21T09:50:47.443193+00:00 heroku[observer.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-21T09:50:47.425787+00:00 heroku[observer.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-21T09:50:49.806923+00:00 heroku[observer.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby observer.rb`
2015-02-21T09:50:50.414194+00:00 heroku[observer.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966632+00:00 app[observer.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tweetstream-2.6.1/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:449:in `block in connect': Failed to reconnect after 6 tries. (TweetStream::ReconnectError)
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966647+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/em-twitter-0.3.5/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:297:in `call'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966648+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/em-twitter-0.3.5/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:297:in `invoke_callback'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966650+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/em-twitter-0.3.5/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:269:in `rescue in schedule_reconnect'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966657+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1457:in `event_callback'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966652+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/em-twitter-0.3.5/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:264:in `schedule_reconnect'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966656+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/em-twitter-0.3.5/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:92:in `unbind'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966660+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966658+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2015-02-21T10:01:22.966661+00:00 app[observer.1]:   from observer.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

また、rubyについては始めたばかりなのでソースコードなどにおかしなところがあれば、知見をお持ちの方に指摘いただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

念のために確認ですが、Herokuに環境変数は設定してありますか？
以下のコードで環境変数を使っているので、まず最初に環境変数が入っていないと正しく動かないと思います。

```
Parse.init :application_id => ENV['PARSE_APP_ID'],
           :api_key        => ENV['PARSE_API_KEY']

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
  config.consumer_secret    = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
  config.oauth_token        = ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN']
  config.oauth_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET']
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end
```

ローカルで動いているのであればそれぐらいしか違いが思いつかないので、念のため確認をお願いします。

Comment: すみません。ご指摘の通り環境変数の設定が誤っていました。環境変数を記載した.envファイルをherokuのgitリポジトリにpushすれば環境変数を設定してくれるものだと勘違いしていました。

`git config`コマンドで改めて環境を変数を設定したところ期待動作を確認できました。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ローカルでの Ruby のバージョンと Heroku での Ruby のバージョンが違うために動作が異なっているのかもしれません（ EventMachine がらみのエラーが生じ得ます）。

Junichi Ito さんの確認（[環境変数](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)）に加えて、 Heroku での Ruby バージョンを指定してみてください。

例えば、もしもローカルで Ruby 2.1.5 を使っていれば Gemfile を

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.5"
# プロセス管理
gem 'foreman'
gem 'tweetstream'
gem 'parse-ruby-client'
```

にしてください。

個人的には Twitter 関係の gem は [The Twitter Ruby Gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter) を使った方が良いと思っています（目的にしておられる、他のアカウントのツイートを Streaming で見張っていることも可能で、私も使っています）。
TweetStream 及びそのベースとなっている em-twitter は、最近はあまり更新されておらず、しかも最近の更新に関しては Twitter Ruby Gem 作者の sferik が行っていたりします。
Twitter Ruby Gem は現在 5.14.0 、バージョン6でさらなる Streaming 対応を図ろうとしているところのようです。

おまけ：observer.rb で、二回目の `require 'uri'` は不要です（全く意味が無いです）。

Comment: Junichi Ito さんにご指摘いただいた点を確認したところ問題なく動作致しました。環境変数の問題でした。

streaming apiを利用したアプリをまた別に作成する予定なので教えていただいたTwitter Ruby Gem についても勉強したいと思います。ありがとうございました。

＃ご指摘いただいたRubyバージョンの不一致、不要な`require 'uri'`については修正させていただきました。